# Strange behaviour of UIScrollView as well as UITableView after moving iOS app to iOS 9 from is

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios9

I am working on a iOS app. The app works fine on iOS 8.
but recently I migrate it to iOS 9 and all the scroll view and even tableviews are bit **heavy to scroll**. They are not as smooth as in iOS 8.
Also when I add subviews they gets added slowly that I can see them like animation.
Am I the only one who is facing this issue?
I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and on iOS 9.

Has anything changed in implementing UITableView and UIScrollView in iOS 9?
Please help guys.

Comment: Did you test it in simulator?

Comment: @KChen I did test it on both on simulator and on iPhone 5c.

Comment: Yes, we saw this during the beta. It got better with the 9.0 release. 9.1 is still beta and still noticeable slower. Feels like massive logging - a bit like retro if you think back on iPhone 4, iOS 4 and devs that spammed the log even in release builds. As for Xcode 7.1 beta I have no apps to compare.

Comment: If you open a new project with Xcode 7.1, is it still strange?

Comment: @KChen Yes, it is still on Xcode 7.0.1.

Comment: I am using Xcode 7.0 which doesn't have this problem.